# How can I create an if statement that looks for fetch requests?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, flask, fetch

I am using Flask and Fetch()

I have a form
When text input "a" changes/text is input. 
A fetch request is sent to "/validate-form".

When the submit button at the end of the form is pressed. 
It too submits the form to "/validate-form".

What If else statement can I create, that will be able to distinguish, whether a fetch request is sent or a form is submitted to "/validate-form"

I have tried the below, however "FETCH" keep getting printed to the terminal.

```
@app.route("/validate-form", methods = ["POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "username" in request.form and "password" in request.form:
           print("submitted")
           return "Thanks"
        else:
            print("FETCH")
            return "Thanks"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, it prints "submitted" properly.

The solution I could propose is to use some hidden input which would be sent only if submit button was clicked.

```
<input type="hidden" name="isFormSubmitted" value="true" />
```

**More complete example:**

*Frontend:*

```
<h1>Hello Flask</h1>
<form id="myForm" action="/validate-form" method="POST">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <label>Username</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input type="hidden" name="isFormSubmitted" value="true" />
    <label>Validate when I am changed</label>
    <input name="validate" type="text" id="validate"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>


<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
  const validateInput = document.getElementById("validate");
  //input or change event handler
  validate.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    const data = new FormData(myForm);
    data.set("isFormSubmitted", "false");
    fetch('/validate-form', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
  })
}
</script>
```

*Backend:*

```
@app.route("/validate-form", methods = ["POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.form)
        if request.form["isFormSubmitted"] == "true":
           print("SUBMITTED")
           return "Thanks submitted"
        else:
            print("FETCH")
            return "Thanks fetch"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand what you want and in order to distinguish that, you can test in javascript the event type before your data is sended via “POST” like below:

```
   if(window.event.type === 'submit'){
        // You are sending data
    } else {
       // You are validating data
    }
```